# What does this mean? $ A \subset \bar{A} \subset F $ where $F$ is a closed set containing $A$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I'm having a little trouble visualizing this relation. But here's my thought process:

1. $\bar A$ is the closure of A; i.e. the intersection of all closed sets in A. It is also the smallest closed **superset** of A.
2. F is a closed set containing A.

When I see such a relation I figure the following to some extent must be true:

$ A \le \bar{A} \le F$: I understand how $F$ could be larger than $A$ but I don't think I understand why the closure of $A$ ($\bar A $) could be larger than $A$? The closure should be the intersection of all the closed sets in $A$ so why would such an intersection be larger than set $A$? That's the bit I can't quite grasp.

Is there some sort of diagram or more clear proof that I should be looking at or...?

Comment: $\overline{(0,1)} = [0,1]$ as subsets of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: The closure of $A$ is the intersection of all closed sets **that contain** $A$. In other words, it’s the intersection of a bunch of sets $H$ such that $H\supseteq A$, so of course it also contains $A$ as a subset.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Oh! *face-palm* Guess I didn't read that out quite right. Thank you, again, Brian.

Comment: You’re welcome!

Answer (score 1):

The obvious example would be $\overline{(0,1)}=[0,1]=(0,1)\cup\{0,1\}$, as Daniel Fischer notes in the comment.

But note that $\overline{\Bbb Q}=\Bbb R$, so the closure can not only be strictly larger as a set, but can be *much* larger in cardinality as well.